# jquery datatable last version custom parameters

Tags: jquery, datatables

I take the last version of jquery datatable.

My application use server side filtering.

When I try add custom parameter I got an error:

Working code

```
 oTable = $('#kid_list_table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                'url': url,
                "type": "POST",
                'beforeSend': function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
                 }
            });
```

Fail when adding custom parameters

```
 oTable = $('#kid_list_table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                'url': url,
                "type": "POST",
                'beforeSend': function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
                 }
            },
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.extra_search = "test";
            });
```

The error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined**

[image]

How Adding custom params without get this error

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the function that manipulates the data object *inside* the ajax function:

```
oTable = $('#kid_list_table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": url,
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d.extra_search = "test";
                },
                "beforeSend": function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authData.token);
                 }
            });
```

Datatables documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax